# Extending class methods in C++ with templates

Tags: c++, member-functions, function-templates

In contrast with other languages, C++ classes cannot be extended once defined.
This is why free functions are preferable to member functions because these are more general way to extend the behavior of a class.

At the same time, the dot syntax (only used for member functions) can have some notational advantage, for example when there is an object that is "more important" than the rest of the arguments in a function call.

For example,

```
allocator a;
a.allocate(n); // vs. allocate(a, n);
```

This creates a tension in the language.
(A tension that in early C++ contributed to the creation of bloated classes.)

In the best case, the difference is syntactic.
In the worst case the desired syntax using dot forces the methods to be defined inside the class (with the risk of making the class to large by including a lot of member functions).

This is what C++ is so far, and we are used to live with this.

However there is, for some cases a loop hole.
**The question is whether this loop hole is frequently exploited or if it can create problems down the road.**

The fact is that one can emulate extensions of a class by leaving template member function open.

For example:

```
struct A{
    void f(int n) const{...}
    void g(std::string s) const{...};
};
```

The "member" `g` cannot be extended to make this work `A a; a.g(42)`.
However one can do this to make **the syntax** work:

```
struct A{
    void f(int n) const{}
    template<class T> void g(T t) const; // this can be even customized by a user of the library
};

// this can be defined anywhere down the road (but before `A::g<T>` is instantiated I think).
template<> void A::g<int>(int t) const{}
template<> void A::g<std::string>(std::string t) const{}
```

The extension is not general, any extension will have to have a fixed name (and one parameter) in this case but it feels like an extension nevertheless.

**Besides the ugly out of class template code, is there any problem in using this technique to extend classes?**

It is not straightforward in the general case but the technique can be even extended to customize different return types I think (here I used `void` for simplicity, another simple cases is when the return type is `T` itself also).

A problem I can see is that partial specialization is probably very difficult.
Another one is that order of instantiation can be problematic, the customizations need to be defined before first use (?).

Customizing a named function is not very impressive.
But other functions like `template<class T> operator=(T const);` can be customized. Effectively, this is like overloading assignment from outside the class which is not possible by normal means.

Comment: It's not really a loophole, because the class has to explicitly specify the methods that can be extended this way. So it's a way of declaring hooks.

Answer (score 2):

> Besides the ugly out of class template code, is there any problem in using this technique to extend classes?

No, it is called "member templates" and it is a perfectly valid thing in C++.

**Update:**

> I know it is valid. I am wondering if this is a technique frequently used.

I've personally never used it that often. Usually, have been deciding to  implement the whole class as a template rather than focusing on individual functions. Yet at the same time I believe this sort of things depend on what you are trying to achieve and what is your personal taste. I mean it is a feature of the language and so why not use it whenever it feels like it would suit.

Comment: I know it is valid. I am wondering if this is a technique frequently used. I once used it to "overload" the assignment operator of `boost::multi_array<T, D>::operator=<TT>` because the author of the library defined it as a template, but probably for other reasons. It felt like a nasty (but useful) hack.